# Chrome always maximize windows in Gnome Shell

Tags: google-chrome

New Window is maximized automatically, I need a way to stop this. I am on Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome shell. What should I do? What program is responsible for the window size, I notice in Unity Chrome always remember its windows sizes. Firefox, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried starting Google Chrome in a terminal with appropriate switches? For example, you could use `--window-position` and `--window-size`

```
--window-position ⊗ Specify the initial window position: --window-position=x,y    
--window-size ⊗ Specify the initial window size: --window-size=w,h
```

So you'd enter something like `google-chrome --window-position=x,y --window-size=w,h`.

Once you've figured things out by trial and error, you could edit your Google Chrome .desktop file (/usr/share/applications) with a text editor and change the first Exec line from

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U
```

to

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --window-position=x,y --window-size=w,h %U
```

I just use

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --start-maximized %U
```

Once you've edited the .desktop file you don't need to start via a terminal anymore.
These switches and more are found here: [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Comment: I tried "google-chrome --window-position=20,20 --window-size=800,600" but it is not working, the window maximizes completely ignoring the parameters.

Comment: Gnome shell has provided some awesome feature.

Comment: For me, on Lubuntu 12.10, I can get the --window-size switch to work but the --window-position one doesn't do anything logical. I've e-mailed the link to this question to Peter Beverloo from whose site I got those switches.

Comment: No joy. He suggested filing a bug.